# IntegrityError - Text field in HTML not going into Django variable?

Tags: django

I seem to be having a problem with getting data from an html text box assigned into the Django variable.  I am following a very old training on a very old rev with many rev problems as I am using a current rev.  I may have a typo but I believe this is exactly what is in the training. Is there something about the textarea statement that would not assign the result to the Django variable "content" I am missing?  If not I have typed up a huge post with all the code but it is very long and once I got done I thought I would ask this first.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> {{page_name}} - Editing </title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1> Editing {{page_name}}</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/save/">{% csrf_token %}
        <textarea name "content" rows="20" cols="60">{{content}}</textarea><br/>
        <input type = "submit" value="Save Page"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here are the views... error on second to last line

```
def view_page(request, page_name):
    try:
        page=Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response("create.html", {"page_name":page_name})
    content = page.content
    return render_to_response("view.html", {"page_name":page_name, "content":content})

def edit_page(request, page_name):
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
        content = page.content
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        content = ""
    return render_to_response("edit.html",{"page_name":page_name, "content":content},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def save_page(request, page_name):
    content = request.POST.get('content')
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
        page.content = content

    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        page = Page(name=page_name, content = content)
    page.save() # error thrown up on this line for Null data 
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/" + page_name +"/")
```

Comment: can you show the function in your `views.py`?

Comment: yup I will add, but again I just wrote a 4 page description I am siting on I could just post with EVERYTHING.

Comment: the definition of your model in `models.py` may help too

Comment: If that's your exact code copy-pasted here, the problem is `name "content"`. You're missing the `=` sign.

Comment: In which part? In the HTML?  Because that is what I was thinking but the video does not show that.  If in the save_page view I tried that but I must have done it wrong...

Comment: yes because your using `try .. catch` with `DoesNotExist` maybe you could use `get_object_or_404` instead

Comment: THANKS CHRIS THAT DID IT...I knew this one was my fault.  I was thinking a different spot but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

As posted by Chris, you are missing the "=" sign in the textarea definition tag.

I would also suggest just using an input type="text", but that's my style. If you need it, then forget I wrote it.

I suspect that you've fixed this issue by now :) If so, could you relay your solution?